# ASP DLL inside PHP code

Tags: php, dll, com

Is there any possibility to import an ASP .DLL to my php code and use it,
because the .dll includes a function which I have to use inside my php code ?
 I know it sounds crazy but you never know...
thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at the [COM library](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.com.php), as that is able to do so.